# Kendogrid "Read" and "binding" functionality

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am very new to this kendogrid. I am exploring a project that includes the kendogrid implementation. This is line where I got stuck.

```
$('#tbl').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```

I know that this line is being used to retrieve/refresh data but I am not understading why this `'kendoGrid'` is being passed to `data()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how a Kendo UI widget instance is retrieved in general. The approach follows the convention with regard to jQuery plugins.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/events-and-methods#getting-widget-references

Comment: In the given example they are referring to "kendogridautocompelte". So this is different plugin of kendoGrid?

Comment: There is no such thing as kendogridautocompelte on that page. AutoComplete is a different Kendo UI widget, and is simply used as an example in the code snippets.

Comment: Okay... so similarly it will load kendoGrid. So this is simply a functionality of jquery. Thanks for the help me understand this!